# How can I start a script after connecting via xrdp?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, unity, xrdp

I'm trying to start a script after connecting to XRDP but, the script doesn't run. I've tried adding the script to */etc/xdg/autostart*, *~/.config/autostart*. When I place them here, it starts when I log in at the desktop itself but, it doesn't start when I log in via XRDP. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I've narrowed down the issue to it being Unity Desktop Environment. If I were to use other Desktop Environments, it works properly so, I've decided to just use XFCE instead of Unity.